# Two graphs in the same axes \addplot3 (pgfplots)

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I want to draw two graphs using pgfplots. Here's the first one:
[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-pi,
    xmax=pi,
    ymin=-pi,
    ymax=pi,
    zmin=0,
    zmax=2.5,
    xlabel={$\varkappa_x$},
    ylabel={$\varkappa_y$},
    zlabel={$\omega$},
    xtick={-pi,-pi/2,0,pi/2,pi},
    xticklabels={$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$},
    ytick={-pi,-pi/2,0,pi/2,pi},
    yticklabels={$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$}
    ]
    \addplot3[surf,domain=-pi:pi,samples=40]{sqrt(2*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^2+sin(deg(x/2))^2+sin(deg(y/2))^2-sqrt(4*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^4+(sin(deg(x/2))^2-sin(deg(y/2))^2)^2))};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

,
here's the second one:
[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-pi,
    xmax=pi,
    ymin=-pi,
    ymax=pi,
    zmin=0,
    zmax=2.5,
    xlabel={$\varkappa_x$},
    ylabel={$\varkappa_y$},
    zlabel={$\omega$},
    xtick={-pi,-pi/2,0,pi/2,pi},
    xticklabels={$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$},
    ytick={-pi,-pi/2,0,pi/2,pi},
    yticklabels={$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$}
    ]
    \addplot3[surf,domain=-pi:pi,samples=40]{sqrt(2*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^2+sin(deg(x/2))^2+sin(deg(y/2))^2+sqrt(4*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^4+(sin(deg(x/2))^2-sin(deg(y/2))^2)^2))};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

.

When I try to plot both graphs in the same axes, this is what happens

[image]

```
        \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-pi,
        xmax=pi,
        ymin=-pi,
        ymax=pi,
        zmin=0,
        zmax=2.5,
        xlabel={$\varkappa_x$},
        ylabel={$\varkappa_y$},
        zlabel={$\omega$},
        xtick={-pi,-pi/2,0,pi/2,pi},
        xticklabels={$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$},
        ytick={-pi,-pi/2,0,pi/2,pi},
        yticklabels={$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$}
        ]
        \addplot3[surf,domain=-pi:pi,samples=40]{sqrt(2*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^2+sin(deg(x/2))^2+sin(deg(y/2))^2-sqrt(4*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^4+(sin(deg(x/2))^2-sin(deg(y/2))^2)^2))};
        \addplot3[surf,domain=-pi:pi,samples=40]{sqrt(2*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^2+sin(deg(x/2))^2+sin(deg(y/2))^2+sqrt(4*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^4+(sin(deg(x/2))^2-sin(deg(y/2))^2)^2))};
     \end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

that is, my second graph overlaps the first one in the vicinity of zero. How can I make the first graph in the vicinity of zero overlap with the second one? It is clear that if I change the sequence of calling \addplot3, then the first graph will overlap with the second one everywhere. I would like only in the vicinity of zero, so that the picture looks correct similar as this
[image]

TeX file

```
    \documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}


\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    xmin=-pi,
                    xmax=pi,
                    ymin=-pi,
                    ymax=pi,
                    zmin=0,
                    zmax=2.5,
                    xlabel={$\varkappa_x$},
                    ylabel={$\varkappa_y$},
                    zlabel={$\omega$},
                    xtick={-pi,-pi/2,0,pi/2,pi},
                    xticklabels={$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$},
                    ytick={-pi,-pi/2,0,pi/2,pi},
                    yticklabels={$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$}
                    ]
                    \addplot3[surf,domain=-pi:pi,samples=35]{sqrt(2*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^2+sin(deg(x/2))^2+sin(deg(y/2))^2-sqrt(4*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^4+(sin(deg(x/2))^2-sin(deg(y/2))^2)^2))};
                    \addplot3[surf,domain=-pi:pi,samples=35]{sqrt(2*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^2+sin(deg(x/2))^2+sin(deg(y/2))^2+sqrt(4*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^4+(sin(deg(x/2))^2-sin(deg(y/2))^2)^2))};
                \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67924529/two-graphs-in-the-same-axes-addplot3-pgfplots

Comment: This is a typical situation showing a limitation of tikz and tikz-based package: not a 3D. We can overcome it by using 3D engine like Asymptote https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/

Comment: Unfortunate my upvote is locked. I would like to change it to an downvote as OP is wasting my time by asking the exact same question again - see link by @Tom. Let us close this spam.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a repost of an old question - spam

Answer (score 1):

PGFPlots do not have a z-buffer extending outside the individual plots, so it is up to you to make the plots in the correct order.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-pi, xmax=pi,
ymin=-pi, ymax=pi,
zmin=0, zmax=2.5,
xlabel={$\varkappa_x$}, ylabel={$\varkappa_y$}, zlabel={$\omega$},
xtick={-pi,-pi/2,0,pi/2,pi},
xticklabels={$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$},
ytick={-pi,-pi/2,0,pi/2,pi},
yticklabels={$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$}
]
\addplot3[surf, domain=-pi:pi, samples=35]{sqrt(2*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^2+sin(deg(x/2))^2+sin(deg(y/2))^2-sqrt(4*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^4+(sin(deg(x/2))^2-sin(deg(y/2))^2)^2))};
\addplot3[surf, domain=-pi:pi, samples=35]{sqrt(2*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^2+sin(deg(x/2))^2+sin(deg(y/2))^2+sqrt(4*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^4+(sin(deg(x/2))^2-sin(deg(y/2))^2)^2))};
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:pi, y domain=-pi:0, samples=18, forget plot]{sqrt(2*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^2+sin(deg(x/2))^2+sin(deg(y/2))^2-sqrt(4*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^4+(sin(deg(x/2))^2-sin(deg(y/2))^2)^2))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two surface plots]

Edit: With different colors and better line joints.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-pi, xmax=pi,
ymin=-pi, ymax=pi,
zmin=0, zmax=2.5,
xlabel={$\varkappa_x$}, ylabel={$\varkappa_y$}, zlabel={$\omega$},
xtick={-pi,-pi/2,0,pi/2,pi},
xticklabels={$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$},
ytick={-pi,-pi/2,0,pi/2,pi},
yticklabels={$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$},
line join=bevel, point meta rel=per plot,
]
\addplot3[surf, domain=-pi:pi, samples=35, colormap/hot,  point meta min=-1, point meta max=1.5]{sqrt(2*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^2+sin(deg(x/2))^2+sin(deg(y/2))^2-sqrt(4*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^4+(sin(deg(x/2))^2-sin(deg(y/2))^2)^2))};
\addplot3[surf, domain=-pi:pi, samples=35, colormap/cool, point meta min=0, point meta max=2.5]{sqrt(2*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^2+sin(deg(x/2))^2+sin(deg(y/2))^2+sqrt(4*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^4+(sin(deg(x/2))^2-sin(deg(y/2))^2)^2))};
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:pi, y domain=-pi:0, samples=18, forget plot, colormap/hot, point meta min=-1,point meta max=1.5]{sqrt(2*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^2+sin(deg(x/2))^2+sin(deg(y/2))^2-sqrt(4*sin(deg((x+y)/2))^4+(sin(deg(x/2))^2-sin(deg(y/2))^2)^2))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two surface plots red and blue]

Comment: I now see that this was asked AND answered in 2021. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67924529/two-graphs-in-the-same-axes-addplot3-pgfplots

Comment: Thanks, I thought in TeXexchange I could get more information to solve this problem

Comment: Sorry for your waste time